# Jenkins: CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake

Tags: qt, jenkins, protocol-buffers

I try running a CMakeLists.txt on a Jenkins build server. The CMakeLists.txt with protobuf invocation looks like this:

```
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})

protobuf_generate_cpp(comm.pb.cc     comm.pb.h     proto/comm.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(comm_ccd.pb.cc comm_ccd.pb.h proto/comm_ccd.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(comm_cda.pb.cc comm_cda.pb.h proto/comm_cda.proto)
protobuf_generate_cpp(comm_plc.pb.cc comm_plc.pb.h proto/comm_plc.proto)
```

When running the CMakeLists on a Jenkins, following error is generated:

```
12:01:11 CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:425 (file):
12:01:11   file STRINGS file "/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h"
12:01:11   cannot be read.
12:01:11 Call Stack (most recent call first):
12:01:11   libraries/ScAPIProtocol/CMakeLists.txt:35 (find_package)
```

CMake command:

```
12:01:11 + cd build
12:01:11 + cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/opt/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64 -DProtobuf_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local ../code
```

Comment: Does `/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h` exist? It seems to be missing or broken.

Comment: My first attempt was copying all necessary files needed for compilation to the jenkins server. Afterwards, I even compiled the protobuf files on the build server from source. I checked the directory and everything seems ok, as all the files (including common.h) exist.

Comment: Check file permissions. It may have no read rights for all users.

Comment: I allready checked it. Everything is fine and accessible. Also, regarding user and group access rights:
I tried using the Authorization plugin for Jenkins. I don't know which user effectively calls the cmake command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution now:
It was like @Michał Walenciak suggested. You have to check the permissions on the cmake call.

First of all, I had to adjust the cmake call to

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/opt/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64
      -DProtobuf_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include
      -DProtobuf_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so ../code
```

Furthermore, jenkins executes this bash call with the "jenkins" user, belonging to the "jenkins" group. For it to read the protobuf files correctly, you have to change the user and group of specified include and lib directories as follows:

```
$ sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /usr/local/include
$ sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /usr/local/lib
```

I hope this helps, at least it did in my case. Thanks to Michał.